# Angular testing: Protractor can't get input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm new to Protractor..I think I understood the basic principles in spite of the lacking documentation, but I can't find a way to solve this problem.

Given this code:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('canvas.description')).sendKeys('My description');
var description = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('canvas.description'));
expect(description.getText()).toEqual('My description');
```

I can see that the input gets the text it's inserting and the model updates with the same value, but the test failures 'cause description.getText() returns '' (empty string).

Is there a different way to catch values inside inputs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Apparently there is a quirk with Selenium WebDriver. See [here.](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/140#issuecomment-25654606)

Try:

```
description.getAttribute('value');
```

Note, that `getAttribute` returns a promise, so if you need to use this value somehow you'll have to use a `then` clause:

```
description.getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
    //Do something with value
});
```

Comment: By changing getAttributes with getAttribute, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Note: `getAttribute('value`)` returns a promise so you'll need to do something like this: `getAttribute('value').then(function(value){ console.log(value) });`

Comment: chromedriver: chromedriver_91.0.4472.101  element value is `null`