# Get value of input for testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am trying to write simple e2e test, using angular, karma and protractor. I figure out that I can get the text from some element using `getText()` but I can't find the right way to get the value of input. The sample of my code below:

```
this.page =  $('.content-area');
this.userEmail = this.page.element(by.css('.email > input'));

this.expectHomeEmail = function(text) {
            expect(this.userEmail.isDisplayed()).toBeTrue();
            expect(this.userEmail.getValue()).toBe(text);
};
```

The error that I get looks like:

- TypeError: undefined is not a function

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular testing: Protractor can't get input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538185/angular-testing-protractor-cant-get-input-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to getText on an input in protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310442/how-to-gettext-on-an-input-in-protractor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
this.userEmail.getAttribute('value')
```